# How to change the size of the font of a Label to take the maximum size

Tags: javafx-2

I have a `Label` in a `Scene`. I need to get always the largest font size for the text in it, so that the text always takes the maximum size in the available size of the label.

How can I do that?

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: I used the link in the accepted answer ;-)

Comment: But it uses a Text rather than a Label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if we have a way to set font size according to the size of the container. But you could scale the text vertically or horizontally to fit the container bounds. Check out the following ...

[Scaling a textbox without truncating text within it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192557/scaling-a-textbox-without-truncating-text-within-it/13300657#13300657)

Comment: works realy good for me, thx. I also set the scaley to the same value, so that the proportions are normal again.

Answer (score 9):

```
final double MAX_FONT_SIZE = 30.0; // define max font size you need
label.setFont(new Font(MAX_FONT_SIZE)); // set to Label
```

Comment: that does not solve my problem. When I set a very big font size, then the text will be cutted with ...

I think the question is a bit unclear, I will try to fix this.