# JavaFX Control sizing

Tags: javafx, sizing

I have a JavaFX app with ComboBoxes and labels. It looks fine in Windows XP but in Windows 7, the font sizes and comboboxe sizes are larger. I tried sizing the comboboxes with setstyle CSS with no results.

Comment: Please post some code so we can see what you have tried and what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

The fact that changing PC's result is different is to be considered based on PC screen resolution, And the fact that you can not modify the size seems to be a problem you have in both codes, only that on w.XP is a negligible problem.

A) Advanced solution:

1: Determine the screen size [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3680236/6598728)

2: Cenge the size [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13300657/6598728)

B) Not so advanced solution:

1: ask from the user the size of the text he like

2: cange the size (like A.2)